# Solving $z^4*\overline{z}=-1+\sqrt{3}i$

Tags: complex-numbers

need some help solving this problem:

$z^4*\overline{z}=-1+\sqrt{3}i$$\DeclareMathOperator{\cis}{cis}$

The answer is: $z_k=(2*{2^{1/5}})^{1/5}\cis(\frac{2\pi+6\pi*k}{15})$, 
$k=0,1,2,3,4$.

I tried using De Moivre to solve it but I got the wrong answer :

I substituted $z=r*\cis(\alpha)$

$r^4*\cis(4\alpha)*r*\cis(-\alpha)=2\cis(\frac{2\pi}{3})$

$r^5*\cis(3\alpha)=2\cis(\frac{2\pi}{3})$

$r*\cis(\frac{3\alpha}{5})=2^{1/5}\cis(\frac{\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi*k}{5})=2^{1/5}\cis(\frac{2\pi+6\pi*k}{15})$

from here I just couldn't find a way to get to the right answer.

Comment: The answer given is wrong. Taking  modulus the given equation immediately gives $|z|=2^{1/5}$.

Comment: What does $cis$ stand for? Is $cis(x):=e^{ix}$? Your answer is the correct one by the way

Comment: @David $\operatorname{cis}(x)=\cos x+i\sin x$

Comment: OK, that's the same thing as $e^{ix}$ then

Comment: "Solving $z^4*\overline{z}=-1+\sqrt{3}i$$\DeclareMathOperator{\cis}{cis}$" is a million times better than a title like "Q: Complex numbers".  Do something like that next time. In general, repeating your tags in the title field is a bad idea.   Unless you're trying to disinterest people in your question, then it's a bang-up idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since $r^5\operatorname{cis}3\alpha=2\operatorname{cis}\frac{2\pi(1+3n)}{3}$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$, $r=2^{1/5}$ while $\alpha=\frac{2\pi(1+3n)}{9}$ with $0\le n\le4$.